# Помощь с пониманием алгоритма генетического алгоритма на примере задачи

Tags: c#, алгоритм, генетический-алгоритм

Проблема с задачей.

> Вы работаете с компанией по доставке товаров, которая ежедневно пользуется платной
>   автомобильной дорогой. Плата за путешествие взимается на 10-и пунктах оплаты
>   расположенных вдоль дороги. Водителям компании необходимо преодолеть весь путь,
>   оплатив комиссию за проезд на каждом из пунктов.
>   Сложность состоит в том, что по правилам, комиссию можно оплачивать только одной
>   единственной монетой. В случае, если ее номинал выше, чем стоимость проезда,
>   водитель сдачу не получает и остаток сгорает. Если же монета, наоборот, не полностью
>   покрывает стоимость проезда, то вашей компании насчитывается долг. При этом
>   стоимость проезда на каждом из пунктов абсолютно произвольно изменяется в конце дня,
>   и может варьироваться в диапазоне от 1-ой до 10-и копеек включительно. Также
>   известно, что несколько пунктов оплаты могут выставлять одну и ту же стоимость
>   проезда, а общая сумма проезда через все пункты будет всегда больше 55-и копеек.
>   Каждому водителю в начале пути выдается 10 монет, по одной монете каждого
>   достоинства (т.е. одна монета достоинством в копейку, одна монета достоинством в две
>   копейки, одна - три, и так далее, до десяти копеек включительно). Используя генетический
>   алгоритм, вам необходимо найти такую стратегию оплат путешествия, при которой долг
>   водителя в конце пути будет минимальным. Алгоритм будет применяться компанией в
>   начале каждого дня, и использовать данные по новым, только что установленным,
>   размерам комиссий на пунктах оплат для получения новой стратегии для водителей.
>
> Входящие параметры:
>   Массив из десяти произвольных чисел от 1 до 10, представляющих собой размеры
>   комиссий на каждом из пунктов. Числа в массиве могут повторятся, и их сумма будет
>   всегда больше чем 55.
>
> Выходные данные:
>   Массив из десяти чисел, представляющих собой достоинства монет, расположенные в
>   порядке, оптимальном для оплат на каждом из пунктов (так чтобы долг компании после
>   всех оплат был минимальным).

Был вовлечен в написание так что забыл про одно из условий ,это не нахождение бесплатного проезда а нахождение оптимального тк бесплатный проезд

> Числа в массиве могут повторятся, и их сумма будет
>   всегда больше чем 55.

невозможен. Мне кажется я иду в нужное русло но отбор нужно менять, как и генерацию водителей.
Вот мой код:

```
    namespace ConsoleApplication16
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
        Random rand = new Random();
        bool weNeedContinue = true;          
        int[] propuski1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] bestWay = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] propuski = PropuskiPrice(propuski1);
        int[] car = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        GenerateCar(car,bestWay);
        int[] moneyChange = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };                    
        while(weNeedContinue == true)
        {
            GettingBest(moneyChange, car, propuski, bestWay);
            GenerateCar(car, bestWay);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("luchshii put " + bestWay[i]);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" car " + car[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(" propusk " + propuski[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            ContinueOrNot(bestWay, weNeedContinue);
        }          

    }

    public static int[] PropuskiPrice(int[] a)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int summa = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rand.Next(10) + 1;
            summa += a[i];
            if (i == 9 && summa <= 55)
            {
                PropuskiPrice(a);
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////Создаем водителя/////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    public static int[]  GenerateCar(int[] a,int[] c)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if(c[i] != 0)
            {
                a[i] = c[i];
                continue;
            }
            int b = rand.Next(1, 11);
            if (!a.Contains(b))
            {
                a[i] = b;
            }
            else
                i--;
            if(i == a.Length - 1 )
            {

            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////INIT////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    static void GettingBest(int[] change,int[] car,int[] propuski,int[] bestOne)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
            {
                change[i] = car[i] - propuski[i];
                if (change[i] == 0)
                {
                    bestOne[i] = car[i];
                /*Console.WriteLine("Карман" + car[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("Цена" + propuski[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("Лучший путь"+ bestOne[i]);*/
                }
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (change[i] == -1 || change[i] == 1)
            {
                bestOne[i] = car[i];
                Console.WriteLine(bestOne[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (change[i] == -2 || change[i] == 2)
            {
                bestOne[i] = car[i];
                Console.WriteLine(bestOne[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (change[i] == -3 || change[i] == 3)
            {
                bestOne[i] = car[i];
                Console.WriteLine(bestOne[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////Prodoljat ili net////////////////////////////// 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////


    static void ContinueOrNot(int[] bestWay,bool weNeedContinue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (bestWay[i] != 0)
            {
                weNeedContinue = true;
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                weNeedContinue = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
    }
```

Собственно метод  **PropuskiPrice(int[] a)** - это генерация цен на пропусках при запуске программы.

**GenerateCar(int[] a,int[] c)** - создание водителя, это собственно я и хотел бы как то поменять, тк метод не удовлетворяет требованиям полного отбора,он только подберет значения которые подходят более-менее.

**GettingBest(int[] change,int[] car,int[] propuski,int[] bestOne)** - тоже не удовлетворяет требованиям полного отбора,он только подберет значения которые подходят более-менее.

**ContinueOrNot(int[] bestWay,bool weNeedContinue)** - проверка на продолжение.

В общем я в тупике.Если у кого будут идеи как из этого слепить то что мне нужно буду очень признателен.

P.S.(Я не прошу написать все за меня,я прошу лишь посмотреть на это и подсказать где в корне поменять логику что бы получилось то что нужно)

P.S.s.(Я конечно же не буду против если кто то конкретно скажет что переделать(= )

P.S.s.s.(Прошу не оценивать "качество кода", я буквально 2 недели учусь, если кто то подскажет как и код оптимизировать глядя на данный пример буду очень благодарен!)

Comment: Полный пример решения вашей задачи [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860092/222542)